# SQL join filter condition, mysql

Tags: mysql, sql, join, filter, where-clause

I have a two tables that look like this (this is an example of what I actually have).

Table 1:

```
Yr, Value
1990, 1
1990, 2
1991, 2
1992, 3
```

Table 2:

```
Dte, Value2, ID
1/1/1990, 10, 1
1/2/1990, 11, 1
1/3/1990, 12, 2
1/1/1991, 20, 1
1/2/1991, 21, 2
```

I would like to join the two tables first using a left join first, then discard some of the values from the joined set, then group by `ID`.  The code I have written looks something like this:

```
    select avg(Value2) v2 
     from table2 
left join table1 on (year(dte)=yr) 
    where Value>1 
 group by ID;
```

Does the join get performed first and then the filter condition in the `where` statement discard the rows from the merged table or does the where condition get evaluated first and then the join?  The example above is just for illustration and this is a more general question about how the SQL does the operation.

Comment: They're sort of done at the same time, operating a on row-by-row basic. The actual order may depend on the DBMS' optimizers - sometimes it makes sense to do a where first to reduce how many rows actually need to be joined. In other cases it makes more sense to join first then do a where filter.

Comment: just an opinion, but you can easily find this kind of thing out by testing it yourself.  Run the query with and without the WHERE clause and compare the results.

Comment: @MarcB the question is about the optimization of mysql specifically.

Comment: my apologies because i think i was unclear: i am not interested about the optimization but rather the order of evaluation.  i need the join to occur first and am wondering how to make that happen.

Comment: I don't know about MySQL specifically, but generally I belive most RDBMSs **DO NOT** guarantee an order, because that would potentially constrain optimization of the statement.  It's best not to rely on this in any case.  What is it you're trying to accomplish, that you need the `JOIN` 'performed first'?  Alternatively, maybe put the conditions in the `WHERE` clause into the `JOIN` (... hey, it's worth a shot).

Comment: basically i have a bunch of dates with prices, i then join another table to each date with last year's end of year market cap. so it's a situation where a row on the right hand table matches many rows in the left hand table. after this i would like to drop all the rows IN A PARTICULAR YEAR that are below a certain market cap. after this i group the results by ID.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

this depends on the order in which your tables are stated and the order of your `where`s. in this case, the where is executed afterwards. so it would be more efficient to declare the tables in the inverse order, since you have the where clause for table1.

the way you do it, all the rows from table1 are joined with the rows from table2 using the on-clause to narrow it down. then, last, the where clause is used on the result of the join. however, like this:

```
   select avg(Value2) v2 
     from table1 
left join table2 on (year(dte)=yr) 
    where Value>1 
 group by ID;
```

the where clause is executed first on table1, then the join is performed using the on-clause. this is done on the already reduced version of table1, and therefor it's more efficient.

Comment: Interesting: I would actually like MySQL to do the join first.  In the example above it doesn't matter but for the much larger thing I am doing I actually need it to do the join first and then remove the rows.  What is the way to ensure this? You mentioned it's the ordering of the tables.. how did you know this?

Comment: @Alex note that it's the ordering of the tables **in relation to the ordering of the where clauses** that determine this. a senior programmer taught me this at a mysql specific job i did.

Comment: could you please elaborate? does this mean that the where clause works on the table immediately before it? please explain

Comment: @Alex the way i was taught, the first where clause is executed as soon as possible, and then the second one is executed as soon as possible and so on. your where clause references table1, so in you're original query it's not possible to execute that where clause until after the join.